# Potential DoS in emailing admin on error pages

Tags: email, denial-of-service

In my website, the backend sends an email to the sysadmin whenever there is an Error 500 with the logs and other data about the error.

How can I prevent a cracker from intentionally triggering the Error 500 and, in turn, flooding the mail server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a legitimate use case that triggers a status code 500, there is little you can do to prevent someone from doing just that.

Of course you can add some logic to the website, resulting in the **ban** of **an offender** (e.g. identified via source IP address) **after triggering a status code 500 too often in a defined amount of time**, but finding a suitable threshold can be tricky. You risk banning legitimate users, if you are not careful. Add the possibility of banning a big network because a single offender behind a NAT triggers the protection mechanism, and this option doesn't seem too attractive any more.

The easier solution is **reconsidering your alerting mechanism**. Why do you need an email every time a single status code 500 is triggered. You can define thresholds on this level as well. To defined suitable thresholds, you should think about the purpose of this mechanism.

**Do you want to find new bugs?** You should alert only the first few errors for a specific request and investigate the problem. No need to report an already known issue again.

**Do you want to identify attacks?** You should only alert if a significant amount of errors are triggered. In this case, it is sufficient to send a single mail to initiate further investigation. The response team can gather everything else from the log files.

Those are just two examples. Your intention behind this type of alerting might be entirely different, so you have to come up with a suitable solution that fits your need. Nevertheless, I would consider revamping your alerting strategy more fruitful than preventing its misuse.

Answer (score 0):

"The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 500 Internal Server Error server error response code indicates that the server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request."[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/500) A 500 status code would be generated by a web client, and not the mail server itself. This is the catch all error code for server side errors and can be caused by web client software, network conditions, or the application server configuration and capacity.

Mail servers are hot targets for malicious actors, and using a SaaS provider could be the more secure option. If it cannot be avoided, configuring rate limiting on the mail server used in conjunction with a tool like **fail2ban** would be the best solutions to prevent such a DoS.

Comment: Isn't it the web server that returns a 500 code in OP's question? Not the mail server.

Comment: @FutureSecurity, You are correct, will make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Add trigger hardware firewall ban IP list live. Something like 5-10 response time will do?

When I attack a site, I just figure out what takes the longest in mysql, then send in proxy bots to randomly visit the most queries, and have the proxy list continually updated. So you can't ban your way out of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of emailing the log, send the admin an email notification that tells them to log in to view a log. Then there is no reason to send multiple emails in a short period of time.

Send a "There is new log information you need to view" email once and don't send more emails until either

1. The admin logs in to view the log files, presumably fixes the problem, and logs out.
2. 24 hours have passed since the admin viewed the log. (Measured by how much time has passed since the admin logged in to this service or logged out.)

This way the admin will only get one email if something goes wrong while they're sleeping. And because of the 24 hour thing they will get reminder emails if they missed or ignored one.

The challenge is making sure whatever service you use to display logs does client authentication correctly and is still accessible if the website goes down. You could write a shell script which displayed this information (and another script which the admin remembers to run after fixing things) then let the admin use SSH for authentication and encryption.

(By the way, I assume you're not using end-to-end encryption in your emails. Almost no one does. That might be bad because the log items potentially contain sensitive information.)

Doing this over HTTP is possible, but you probably want to use a more reliable lighter-weight HTTP daemon on a different port, dedicated soley to helping the admin respond to errors from the normal HTTP daemon. Maybe custom software built around a program that does the absolute bare minimum for responding to HTTP requests.